# Prefix Header import in another project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I've a framework project let say ProjectA which is included in another iPhone project ProjectB, so ProjectB is dependent on ProjectA.
ProjectA has a prefix header file in which I've imported one header file of a clss written in ProjectA itself, so this import will be placed in all the classes of ProjectA.
Now what I need is, that imported header has to take place in all the class files inside ProjectB which is dependent on ProjectA.

Please give me suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try import file in .pch (not sure )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the code file for ProjectB...

Alternatively, go to the build settings, search for 'prefix' and edit the path which tells the project where the .pch file that it should use is.

Comment: You mean from ProjectB? ProjectB also has a seperate prefix header file configured

Comment: Yes, so edit the ProjectB .pch file or delete it and link to the file from ProjectA.

Comment: I tried to add the import in ProjectB .pch as #import "ClassName.h" also as #import <ProjectA/ClassName.h> for both I'm getting file not found error

Comment: What is the name of the created framework (not the project that creates it)? That is the import to use.